# MySQL funciones y loops

Tags: mysql

Estoy intentando hacer una función y un bucle para encontrar el id mayor de una tabla, he visto que con la función MAX(). pero quiero hacerlo si ella para ver mas código y entenderlo pero no se como hacerlo.----Correccion---- he leído algo sobre los cursores en sal y creo que son un bucle que itera sobre las columnas.... quizás con estos cursores pueda acceder  y almacenar con fetch?

```
create table Clientes(
id_clientes INT auto_increment,
nombre varchar(20) not null,
telefono varchar(15) not null,
dni varchar(12)unique not null,
primary key (id_clientes)
);
INSERT INTO Clientes VALUES(NULL, "PEPE","645768461","34234567A");
INSERT INTO Clientes VALUES(NULL, "JULIAN","645768462","34234562A");
INSERT INTO Clientes VALUES(NULL, "LAURA","645738461","34214567A");

#Crea una función que extraiga usando un bucle el mayor id de un cliente de los que      se encuentran en la tabla de Clientes.
DELIMITER //
CREATE FUNCTION maxId ()
RETURNS INT DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN

    DECLARE x INT DEFAULT id_clientes;
    while id_clientes = x
    select count(*) from clientes where id_clientes > x;
        
    
END
//
DELIMITER ;
```

----EDITO-----
Ahora estoy intentando hacerlo con cursores....

```
declare @mayor_id VARCHAR(15)
DECLARE mayor CURSOR FOR SELECT id_clientes from Clientes
open mayor
fetch next from mayor into @mayor_id
while @@fetch_status = 0 Begin

PRINT @mayor_id


fetch next from mayor into @mayor_id
end
close mayor
deallocate  mayor
//
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: También podrías hacerlo con `ORDER BY` y `LIMIT`

Comment: y con una función y dentro de esta un bucle ? no se podría es que hoy es mi primer dia jajajaja y quiero primero entender el código

Comment: Pasa no tiene sentido hacerlo usando un `while`. Quizás si el objetivo fuese otro... Si queres aprender sobre sintaxis, es mejor [leer el manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/while.html).

Comment: Una función como esa no debería ser determinística.